# How to change the theme for android at runtime in appcelerator

Tags: android, appcelerator

I have add 3 theme into my appcelerator project for android. Now i want to switch between the theme when user click on button. Please advice.

Comment: Please include what you've already tried. It's easier for others to help you when they know what hasn't worked so far and where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Go through below link.
It may help as your requirement:

[runtime-theme-change](https://sriramramani.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/runtime-theme-change/)

Comment: This is less of an answer and more of a comment

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the theme of an existing window, so you'd need to close the existing window and reopen it with the newly selected theme as the value for "theme" in the params for createWindow()